# Redundant & inline functions

Tags: function

What is meant by redundant function? What is the difference between a redundant function & an inline function?

Comment: Ramu, I've edited a couple of your posts to be more grammatically correct. Please try to put a little more effort into this, you'll get better answers this way.

Comment: @swilliams: It's nice to correct spelling/grammar where it may be difficult to understand, but it's also important to recognize that English may not be someone's first language and that "a little more effort" may not be all it takes to nail a language as complex and difficult as English.

Comment: @eyelidlessness, understood, but a "little more effort" could consist of asking a friend or colleague for assistance. I did not mean to sound harsh if that's the way it came across.

Comment: Asking a friend or colleague for assistance with grammar for posting a question on SO? Or are you suggesting that someone with a weak grasp of English should seek help elsewhere? I'm genuinely not understanding your point.

Comment: If I'm asking a question online to a group of people that are speaking a different language, I am going to make an attempt to try to be as clear as possible, otherwise people can only guess what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

A **redundant** function is one which has potentially been superseded by another function, and shouldn't be used anymore.  I guess it can be thought of in the same way as a deprecated function.

An **inline** function, in C and C++, is one which is implemented in the header file rather than the .c or .cpp file.  The compiler will replace all calls to that function with the function body itself, rather than linking to it via the symbol table.  This will make the compiled binaries bigger, but it has the advantage that the function will run a little bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

Another meaning of *redundant function* is to have two functions doing basically the same thing:

```
function Foo(x) { return x * x / 2; }
function Bar(x) { return Math.sqr(x) * 0.5; }
```

or same content in different packages, etc.
As shown, they can be slightly different in behavior (float vs. int, etc.) so one must be careful when pruning them...